# CompletableFuture использует Supplier вместо Callable?

Tags: java, concurrency, completablefuture

Почему completableFuture использует вместо привычного callable supplier, зачем так путать людей привыкших к старому доброму callable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CompletableFuture относится к Java8, а там было внедрены зачатки функционального программирования. Собстенно CompletableFuture может быть расмотренно как монада.

Ну а в функциональном программировании Supplier более знакомое слово, нежели Callable, вот и все + держит общий стандарт. Ведь если бы было наоборот, тоже было бы запутанно, везде Supplier, а тут бац, Callable.

Вторая разница что Callable может бросать исключение, а Supplier нет (Ну разве что RuntimeException). Почему так, сложно сказать.

Comment: Да, поля логику, но насчет того что supplier Не бросает исключения это не так, может забыли упомянуть в javadoc, написал код, нормально возрващается исключение objectCompletableFuture.get());

Comment: Вы навернео неправилььно поняли. `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { throw new Exception(); });` - этот код не скомпилируется. То есть вы не можете внутри Supplier бросить Checked Exception

Comment: не понимаю почему не должен, по какому принципу компилятор понимает это, по вашему? как раз этот код я и скомпилировал и запупустил и нормально выбросился через get. проверьте

Comment: CompletableFuture<Object> objectCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        });
        System.out.println(objectCompletableFuture.get());
        System.out.println(1);

Comment: NullPointerException это Unchecked exception, его можно бросать вне зависимости от того, объявлен throws или нет

Comment: а, да, но зато можно возвращать unchecked exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Если посмотреть [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html), то видно, что данный класс веден с 1.8, следовательно его сразу спроектировали для использования с лямбда-выражениями.

Comment: не совсем понял о чем вы. Плюс если посмотреть callable он тоже помечен как FunctionalInterface.

Comment: думаю здесь, все таки, была задумка использовать новый класс с новыми интерфейсами, но это ИМХО само собой